# SQL integration services выполнение сценария C#

Tags: c#, sql, integration-services

Пытаюсь освоить SSIS.  В проекте  Integration services добавить сценарий на C#, который принимает на вход строку,и выдает результат. Задача: необходимо из SQL запустить пакет SSIS, на вход скормить ему параметр "строка", и получить ответ. Если это возможно, то как это сделать? Гугление никаких результатов не принесло, кроме как скрипта запуска из SSMS, но без параметров. Прошу помощи.

Comment: А зачем тебе C#? Что ты им собрался делать там?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Задача следующая. Есть веб-сервис с WSDL. И есть софт. В нем есть процедура на SQL, которая должна ломиться на этот веб-сервис (SOAP 1.1), отправлять данные и забирать ответ обратно. И потом в софте появляется pop-up с необходимой информацией. Чтобы из SQL напрямую это делать я ничего не нашел.

Comment: А почему вы эту задачу хотите возложить на SQL? Почему бы не написать внешнюю утилиту, которая принимает ответ и заполняет какую-то таблицу на сервере.

Comment: Имхо, если задача просто отправить и получить ответ, то проще сделать SQL CLR сборку. Сервисы интеграции- это больше для какой-то многоступенчатой трансформации данных.

Comment: Просто сама софтина по сути набор SQL процедур. Например в софте мы создаем клиента, и при его сохранении выполняется SQL процедура. И мы можем только в ней встроить это действие. Гугление выдало сразу сервис интеграции. И одно из требований руководства, чтобы как можно меньше прослоек и транзитных БД.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Свой софт уже написан в виде консольного приложения для работы с этим сервисом.

Comment: Вам нужно взаимодействие SQL-Soap?

Comment: @nick_n_a Да. Есть веб-сервис с wsdl. Необходимо воспользоваться его методами.  Если бы это был get запрос, то на SQL с этим проблем не возникает, а вот как сделать с wsdl...

Comment: wsdl можно скачать, и переработать. SQL с XML хорошо дружит. Но... я делал просто SOAP запросы с MSSQL. Создаёте XML, наполняете поля, делаете POST-запрос - и ответ разбираете через XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил проблему написанием CLR для SQL сервера. Столкнулся с проблемой, когда добавляешь ссылку на WCF не WebReference Framework 2.0. При добавлении этой сборки в SQL, сервер требует добавить библиотеки .NET, но там получаем мы кучу ошибок при добавлении сборок. И еще проблема, что External_ACCESS и UNSAFE сборки необходимо подписывать Asymetric KEY. Ниже небольшая инструкция.

1. Т.к. в SQL Database Project для Visual Studio нет возможности добавить ссылку на веб-сервис, необходимо создать отдельную библиотеку классов.
2. В созданной библиотеке классов добавляем ссылку на службу, в окошке нажимаем Дополнительно и нажимаем "Добавить веб-ссылку" (.NET Framework 2.0).
3. Подписываем сборку сертификатом. И Собираем решение.
4. На SQL сервер копируем нашу DLL. Создаем ассиметричный ключ:

   ```
   USE master;   
   GO    

   CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 
   'C:\MyDBApp\SQLCLRTest.dll'     
   CREATE LOGIN SQLCLRTestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey     
   GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO SQLCLRTestLogin;   
   GO
   ```
5. Добавляем сборку на SQL сервер:

   ```
   CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLCLRTest  
   FROM 'C:\MyDBApp\SQLCLRTest.dll'  
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
   ```
6. Далее в SQL Database project создаем SQL CLR C# хранимую процедуру. Добавляем в нее нашу библиотеку. Пишем логику работы с этой библиотекой.
7. И публикуем CLR на SQL сервере.

После этого вызываем процедуру на SQL сервере и получаем ответ от WCF службы.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS - это не самый подходящий инструмент для вашей задачи, насколько ее понял. Основной сценарий использования SSIS - постучаться в источник, в вашем примере - WSDL, забрать данные, что-то с ними сделать и положить в БД. В качестве БД может быть сама БД, текстовый файл или Excel. И еще замечание - SSIS - инструмент пакетной обработки, сформировать ответ в конце работы он может лишь как файл или запись в БД, но не значение в stdout.

Лучше всего создать свой сервер приложений. Но если у вас столь жестко задано ограничение на "неумножение сущностей" MS SQL - попробуйте написать [CLR сборку на C#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/16045.accessing-an-web-service-from-a-sql-server-clr-assembly-procedure-or-function.aspx), которая будет ходить к Web сервису. Можно воспользоваться не менее "старым" способом с MSXML - на [SO есть обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213278/calling-a-soap-webservice-from-tsql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Спасибо. Решили и правда попробовать CLR. Начали с простых тестовых сборок - все работает. Но, столкнулись со следующей проблемой. SQL CLR не умеет дружить с webreference. Для этого необходимо было сделать свою собственную dll, в которой я подключил web reference, и создал класс для работы с сервисом (WsClass). При попытке добавить WSClass в SQL Server, а без нее SQL CLR не опубликовывается,  вылезло, что надо добавить еще кучу .Net сборок. Часть из них получилось добавить, но некоторые, например System.EnterpriseServices.dll добавить не удалось.

Comment: И тут начинается замкнутый круг. Три сборки ссылаются друг на друга и установить их не получается( Использую Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Гм... Плохо... У меня нет готового ответа, в таких случаях выносил логику в сервер приложений, дабы не связываться с пониманием MS (KB922672) - какие dll от будет поддерживать для CLR, а какие - нет. 
Вообще, посмотрел - этот CLR по подходам - древнючесть времен .NET 2.0. Для нормального использования лучше, когда все dll живут в одной директории... Не даром MS сказал, что оно deprecated.
Дополню ответ.

Comment: @AndreySherman Еще описал способ вызова WSDL через MSXML из SP - но это тоже та еще древность.

Comment: А можете по подробнее рассказать про логику в сервере приложений? В принципе с этой проблемой справился, но видимо там еще куча зависимостей, и уже другие ошибки.

Comment: @AndreySherman, сервер приложений упоминал, когда сложные "штуки" с вычислениями или взаимодействиями делал внешний для SQL сервер приложений. А к нему SQL стучался через MSXML, см обновленный ответ.